# Javascript Alertify with return from confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, alertify

I'm trying to use `alertify.js` as a confirmation dialog for all my confirm scripts. But it just isn't working like regular JS `confirm` does. In the code below I never get a `return true`

```
function aConf ( mes ) {
    alertify.confirm( mes, function (e) {
        return e;
    });
}

<a href="#" onclick="if(aConf(\'Are you sure you wish to remove this?\')) { function(); } return false;">Delete</a>
```

Of course if I replace `aConf` with JS' `confirm` it works. So why is `alertify` not sending me back it's outcome?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because confirm is a blocking function (no javascript will run until it returns true/false), and alertify is non-blocking (JS keeps executing). Alertify does not immediately return a true/false, but instead, it probably returns undefined immediately, then it calls a callback function later, after the user clicks OK or Cancel. The return value from that callback function has no effect in your example, because the onclick code has already finished running (because it is non-blocking).

Assuming you are using this: https://github.com/fabien-d/alertify.js/

This is how it actually works with a callback function, not a return value:

```
alertify.confirm( message, function (e) {
    if (e) {
        //after clicking OK
    } else {
        //after clicking Cancel
    }
});
```

For your code sample, you might try something like this:

```
function performDelete ( a_element ) {
    // perform your delete here
    // a_element is the <a> tag that was clicked
}

function confirmAction ( a_element, message, action ) {
    alertify.confirm(message, function(e) {
        if (e) {
            // a_element is the <a> tag that was clicked
            if (action) {
                action(a_element);
            }
        }
    });
}

<a href="#" onclick="confirmAction(this, 'Are you sure you wish to remove this?', performDelete); return false;">Delete</a>
```

EDIT: updated to be a generic confirm dialog that calls a callback function if the user clicks ok.

Comment: That's tha problem. I don't want to make a new function for each time I call it. I wanted to have a general function to display and return. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean, you want the link to navigate to it's href if the user clicks OK? or is there some javascript that performs the action if the user clicks OK? See my updated answer.

Comment: Nope, but what you posted above I can tweak now to do what I needed :) thanks.

Comment: If I enter any URL in href then it will move to that URL then it will show the alert. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

i can solve this problem ,my solution asnyc await function :

Example :

```html
{

function confirmDialogAsync(message = "", okText="Yes", cancelText="No") {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            alertify.confirm(
                message, 
                () => {resolve(true);},
                () => {resolve(false);}
            )
            .set({ title: " " })
            .set({ labels: { ok: okText, cancel: cancelText } });
        });
      }

const saveControlValidation = async () => {

console.log(1); 

 if (!(await confirmDialogAsync("Hello Salih ŞEKER","Hi","Bye"))) {
               return false;
    }

console.log(2);

}

}
```